# grunt watch command not working

Tags: gruntjs, less, watch

my grunt watch task is running, but no changes in .less files are recognized:
here is my grunt file.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // running `grunt less` will compile once
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: false,
                    yuicompress: false,
                },
                files: {
                    "public/css/styles.css": "src/less/styles.less"
                }
            },
            production: {
                options: {
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: true,
                    optimization: 2,
                },
                files: {
                    "public/css/styles.min.css": "src/less/styles.less"
                }
            }
        },
        // running `grunt watch` will watch for changes
        watch: {
            files: "src/less/*.*/*.less",
            tasks: ["less"]
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

Can someone give me a hint, please. Manual trigger of `grunt less` works fine.

Comment: `files: "src/less/*.*/*.less"` - this does not look like a correct pattern for your less files. Should be `"src/less/*.less"` or `"src/less/**/*.less"` or `"src/less/{,*/}*.less"` or something like that depending on actual location of the files (those beside the main `styles.less`).

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  My `.../*.*/...` was wrong for looking in subfolders. Your hint fixes it.